# Stateless Microservice Architecture with oauth2 and JWT

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt, microservices, okta

I've been looking into developing a microservice architecture using SpringBoot and some netflix libraries such as Eureka, Zuul, Ribbon; however, I appear to be hung up with the security design.

My goal is to use a third party web based service such as [Okta.com](http://okta.com) to manage all my users and applications. Okta uses Oauth2 which I believe would make my application stateful. My goal is to keep my application stateless for load balancing purposes.

I would be using the following service module architecture,

```
Gateway Service 
Auth Service (Authenticate against Okta)
Microservice 1 (role_admin, role_sales)
Microservice 2 (role_admin, role_employee)
```

My understanding is when the gateway has requested routing to Microservice 1 or Microservice 2, a token would need to be forwarded along with the request and if no token is present, a request to the Auth Service at the gateway would need to be made in order to obtain a token from Okta using Oauth2.

My next piece of understanding is while using oauth2, when the token is present and has been forwarded along to Microservice 1 or Microservice 2, the token would need to validated against okta again. The groups would be contained within the token.

My question is could Okta be used solely for the purpose of Authenticating and  Authorization, but rather than passing around the stateful oauth2 tokens generated by Okta, create a stateless JWT which would contain roles and user info and pass that back to the microservices?

I'm just wondering how to use a service like Okta in a microservice architecture, but still keep my microservices stateless and I'm not sure my thought process is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is possible and I've written a couple of blog posts on how to do it. This is how JHipster's OAuth microservices are configured as well. However, the main difference is the gateway is stateful because it's more secure to do authorization code flow (with Spring Security) rather than doing implicit flow and keeping the access token on the client. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/17/microservices-spring-boot-2-oauth

Comment: @MattRaible Been following your blogs, but what scenario would you recommend for a kubernetes microservice environment with a keycloak server, the only scenario I can think of is the one from the original poster but would like to keep the access token server side instead of keep passing it on every api request

Comment: Can you please post this as a new question so it gets more visibility (and more answers from experts)?